# How to get datetime local to a specific timezone in javascript?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

In JS, I have a date object whose string value is `Fri Dec 13 2019 15:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`.

Now this should be calgary time.

Now, regardless of where I am in the world, how can I get the calgary-local time from the date object using JS/moment.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Calgary is in the Mountain time zone, not Eastern time.  For most locations in Canada's Mountain time zone, including Calgary, the IANA time zone identifier is `"America/Edmonton"`.

In most modern browsers, the ECMAScript Internationalization API is supported, and thus you can specify a time zone identifier when calling `toLocaleString` as follows:

```js
const dt = new Date();
const s = dt.toLocaleString('en-CA', {timeZone: 'America/Edmonton'});
console.log(s);
```

If you need to support older browsers, you can use Moment-timezone as shown in [the answer by naeramarth7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331236/634824).

Answer (score 0):

Using moment.js:

```js
const out = document.getElementById('output');

// Add required timezones.
// See https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/
moment.tz.add('America/Edmonton|LMT MST MDT MWT MPT|7x.Q 70 60 60 60|0121212121212134121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121|-2yd4q.8 shdq.8 1in0 17d0 hz0 2dB0 1fz0 1a10 11z0 1qN0 WL0 1qN0 11z0 IGN0 8x20 ix0 3NB0 11z0 XQp0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1fz0 1a10 1fz0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 1cN0 1cL0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1lb0 14p0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 11B0 1nX0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0|10e5');
moment.tz.link('America/Edmonton|Canada/Mountain');

// Get the current date in Canada/Mountain time and format it
out.innerText = moment().tz('Canada/Mountain').format('LLL');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.27/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>

<p id="output"></p>
```